# Replacing Ubuntu package with ppa

Tags: 16.04, firefox, ppa

I would like to replace Ubuntu's default Firefox package on my desktop with the "Developer Edition" available as a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora) (I am pretty new to package management).
I expected instructions found on PPA's page to be all I needed ..

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
# "apt-get install --reinstall firefox" just re-install the original package.
```

Okey, Firefox Developer Edition is not getting installed (the original Firefox package is not replaced). And as you can see, apt policy does not show relevant ppa source candidate either.

```
$ sudo apt policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Following that [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302503/why-is-ppa-package-not-taken-into-account) I tried to elevate priority of ppa's package in */etc/apt/preferences.d* with the following snippet:

```
Package: firefox
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 800
```

but apt policy still the same and executing `apt-get update` with `apt-get upgrade` did not changed anything.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` contains two files related to Firefox's PPA:
**»** *ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ubuntu-firefox-aurora-xenial.list* which contains

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu xenial main
#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu xenial main
```

**»** *ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ubuntu-firefox-aurora-xenial.list.save* contains

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu xenial main
```

Thank you for helping me sorting this out.

Comment: I looked into the ppa, and there seems to be build failures (the red X), https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora/+packages. I suggest that you wait until there is a successful build, and try again.

Comment: You could also try: `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa` It gives me access to "firefox-trunc" version 53.0

Comment: @sudodus Well pointed out, thank you I will wait a bit. By the way, can a previous successful build be installed until the last one finally succeeds ?

Comment: @Jean-Marie Thank you for the suggest, the ppa has been fixed in the meantime. Firefox dev edition replaced firefox standard ed.

Comment: @sudodus would you mind create an aswer so that I could upvote it and set this thread as resolved ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the ppa, and there seems to be build failures (the red X),

[launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora/+packages](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora/+packages)

I suggest that you wait until there is a successful build, and try again (or try another version of Firefox).